# Why can't a Dispelling bow apply Dispel to its arrow?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

I was recently building an archer character and was looking at weapon/arrow properties that would be helpful. [Dispelling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/dispelling)(/[burst](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/dispelling-burst)) were some very attractive choices until I looked closer.

My first thought would be that its treated like the elemental properties and dispelling is applied on every hit, which would be very powerful in debuffing. But from the reading it sounds like the weapon/arrow is only now able to now hold the spell, but doesn't even come with it enchanted (in the case of arrows).

My dream of having a bow with the weapon property shooting out dispel is no longer practical, but having a quiver of arrows should be useful still, but not if I need to spend more money just to have each arrow holding the spell as well.

Why doesn't the weapon property come loaded with the spell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't come with an infite supply of dispel magics stored because that would be very overpowered. It, like you want, would allow you to attempt effectively infinite dispels while also attacking as normal.

Keep in mind:

1. Dispelling weapon works like spell storing, which only can be applied to melee weapons:

   > This special ability can only be placed on melee weapons.
2. Dispel magic is a fairly low level spell (3rd level). Assuming your DM allows you to give your arrows or bow Dispelling, your resident magic user could probably load up your bow each day with minimal encouragement.
3. You can get magic ammunition in batches of 50 for the regular price, so, if I were your DM, I'd allow the caster to load up all 50 arrows with 1 cast of dispell magic. Your DM might not be so generous, but you could argue for some group rate (5 or 10 per cast for instance).

Comment: That's because it "functions like" a spell storing weapon, and Ive now read that spell storing can only be applied to melee?

Comment: I don’t know about “very” overpowered; archers really could use an awful lot of love. Still, this does seem like too much, so my vote won’t quibble on the word “very” – +1.

Comment: In my understanding at least, when item/spell/whatever says it "functions like" something else, I assume it has all the same rules as the original item, except for when and where explicitly stated. Your mileage may vary,

Comment: Both [Ranged Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons#TOC-Table:-Ranged-Weapon-Special-Abilities) and [Ammunition](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons#TOC-Table:-Ammunition-Special-Abilities) have their own lists of abilities. Dispelling is on neither of those. In addition, allowing a single cast of *dispel magic* to affect 50 arrows means a decent archer can dispel 3-4 times a round, which is overpowered for exactly the same reason you think infinite dispels are.

Comment: @MrLemon I don't see where those tables limit what weapon special abilities can be possessed by a handcrafted (as opposed to randomly generated) weapon. Some weapon special abilities (e.g. [*lesser designating*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/designating-lesser)) say in their descriptions that their specifically limited to a type of weapon or ammo, but the random generation tables don't seem to limit a weapon special ability's application. Is that information buried elsewhere?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I worked through Ultimate Equipment and looked at the first 30 abilities (A-D). Of these 30, all but Allying, Called and Conductive either appear on all 3 lists or spell out their special requirements in the description. These 3 are listed for both Melee and Ranged. Allying and Called ammunition is just weird, though Conductive ammunition would be sensible. I'm unsure now, but I don't think this will come up often. At any rate, *dispelling* ammunition is still out, since ammunition is not a melee weapon.

Comment: @MrLemon Actually it can be.  *Refine Improvised Weapon* has a long enough duration that you can conceivably use it to add the +1 bonus equivalent you'd need to make +1 arrows *dispelling* +1 arrows.

Comment: Conductive weapons can be melee or ranged, but only work on a "successful attack of the appropriate type", so if its a melee touch attack on a melee weapon and so on. I don't think it would work on ammo, but maybe for ranged abilities?